# Zend Framework: What is the right way of setting default decorators for Zend_Form elements

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

i currently set my default decorators for my `Zend_Form` using a class extending from `Zend_Form` ...

```
class Application_Form_Abstract extends Zend_Form {
    ... 
    function loadDefaultDecorators() {
        if ($this->loadDefaultDecoratorsIsDisabled()) {
            return $this;
        }

        // ... for elements
        $decorators = $this->_elementDecorators;
        if (empty($decorators)) {
            $this->setElementDecorators(array(
                'ViewHelper',
                'Errors',
                array('Description', array('tag' => 'p', 'escape' => false)),
                'Label',
                array('HtmlTag', array('tag' => 'p'))
            ));
```

but i soon realize that that way, i cannot define specific element decorators like

```
$this->addElement('textarea', 'bio', array(
    'decorators' => array(
        'ViewHelper',
        'Errors',
        array('Description', array('tag' => 'p', 'escape' => false)),
        'Label',
        array('HtmlTag', array('tag' => 'p')),
        new Application_Form_Decorator_WmdPreview,
     )
));
```

as they will be over-written by my custom `loadDefaultDecorators()` function. i wonder if there is any way i can set default decorators for element only if they have no set decorators

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the default decorator for 'bio' element by adding a call to setDisableLoadDefaultDecorators()

```
$this->addElement('textarea', 'bio', array(
    'disableLoadDefaultDecorators' => true,
    'decorators' => array(
        'ViewHelper',
        'Errors',
        array('Description', array('tag' => 'p', 'escape' => false)),
        'Label',
        array('HtmlTag', array('tag' => 'p')),
        new Application_Form_Decorator_WmdPreview,
     )
));
```

Answer (score 0):

Also to you save you a headache, displaygroups cannot have the same name as any element that they contain